# Function with parameters of type String or String []

Tags: c#, types

I have a function that needs to accept either a `String` or a `String[]`. I am wondering if there is an or operator (or something similar) I can use within the function definition?

I did think about declaring both parameters as optional, but I do need at least one of them to be supplied.

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Use function overloads.

Comment: Google for ```params```

Comment: you can create two methods with the same name but with different parameters

Comment: I did think about function overload, but seems like a lot of code repetition.

Comment: Code repetition? How? Make the `string` version just call the `string[]` one with only one value in the array

Comment: `public void  FooBar(string foo){ FooBar(new string[]{foo});}`

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto In that case, I can just convert the string to string array before calling the function. I was thinking, maybe there is a magical "or" option.

Comment: Then you'd have the same code repetition everywhere you need to use only one parameter, instead of in a single place like with overloads

Comment: What's so bad about the question to warrant down votes?

Comment: overload doesnt have to mean repetition, it could be that the array version just does foreach x in list do other version of method that takes the single string..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer is **no** there's no *"or"* option for parameters but you can use an alternative.

If the types of your parameter matches you can use `params` keyword which will allow entering zero or more parameters of your specified type:

```
public void SomeMethod(params string[] parameters)
{
    // here parameters can contain 0 or more elements
}
```

You should remember to check if `parameters` contains at least one element.

[Try this online](http://rextester.com/XEDYA93987)